# ZXing Barcode Reader Error

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I used ZXing for using barcode reader.
it worked properly until i add actionbar to my app.(add `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` to dependencies) and then when i click button to open barcode scanner :

```
public void btnBarcode_Click(View view) {
    IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);
}
```

My App exit with this log:

```
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3606)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3601)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    ... 11 more
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:822)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at pl.looksok.listviewdemo.IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.java:179)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at pl.looksok.listviewdemo.IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.java:140)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at pl.looksok.listviewdemo.IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.java:102)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at pl.looksok.listviewdemo.AddNewPerson.btnBarcode_Click(AddNewPerson.java:107)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    ... 14 more
```

is it related with "`android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`" or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:822)
07-20 10:34:03.690: E/AndroidRuntime(23805):    at pl.looksok.listviewdemo.IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.java:179)
```

I was facing that issue before but i can barely remember it but i think you should dig in library and change a request code which starting an Activity for result in zxing library it's probably greater than 65535.

Comment: @mahdi : Trace the initiateScan() function. the error raised at : at pl.looksok.listviewdemo.IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.java:179)

Comment: Correct, Android does not allow request codes greater than 65535 due to limitations imposed by the fragment API. You can see the library's default is correctly sized: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#L112